# Python Venn diagrams - fill and edge color

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-venn

I want to use `matplotlib_venn` library in `Python3` to draw venn diagrams with transparent fill and only edge colored, almost like in the attached but I will only have 2 circles.
I could not find any straightforward way to control the colors. Any ideas, please?
[image]

Currently I have the code:

```
set1 = set([1,2,3])
set2 = set([2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
c = venn2_circles(subsets = [set1,set2], linewidth=1)
c[0].set_color("red")
plt.title("Sample Venn diagram")
plt.show()
```

But this result in coloring the fill and edge together.

Comment: `set_color` or `set_alpha`? If you can show a code where this problem would occur, one might be able to help more in detail.

Comment: I have added the sample code I use.

Comment: If you only want to color the edge, `c[0].set_edgecolor("red")`

Comment: Hi, man. Is there any way to hide the subset label using `subset_label_formatter` argument?